# Configuring Tesseract in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I am facing a very weird problem while configuring Tesseract in Android. Following all required steps described [here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) and SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454848/using-tesseract-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435797/how-to-configure-tesseract-in-eclipse-for-android-development) i have imported [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library in eclipse. **NDK-build** and **ant release** was also successfull. I have used latest ndk version and android sdk v19(4.4.2).

Next, i had imported a sample [project](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) in eclipse written in above blog. All were build successfully. But, when i run the project in a real device, it gives me such a weird error in **onPhotoTaken** event that possible google search can't answer me nothing!

Logcat says:

```
08-22 15:04:44.812: V/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(16578): Before baseApi
08-22 15:04:44.812: D/dalvikvm(16578): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-1/liblept.so 0x41e56b50
08-22 15:04:44.822: D/dalvikvm(16578): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 14% free 4989K/5788K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms
08-22 15:04:44.822: E/dalvikvm(16578): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-1/liblept.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "liblept.so"...
08-22 15:04:44.832: W/dalvikvm(16578): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
08-22 15:04:44.832: D/AndroidRuntime(16578): Shutting down VM
08-22 15:04:44.832: W/dalvikvm(16578): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41be0930)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:211)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:135)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5302)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "liblept.so"...
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578):    ... 17 more
```

Probably the most important part of this error message is:

```
08-22 15:04:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(16578): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "liblept.so"...
```

I checked **liblept.so** is inside the libs folder of library project that i referenced in my sample project.

Can anyone point me the solution or suggestion of this time-killing problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a [problem](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=168) with the NDK toolchain version 4.9.

Try pulling the latest version of the tess-two library code, which includes the following in its `Application.mk`:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

You will need to use the "ndk32" version of the NDK for 32-bit targets.

Comment: I have used all(os, java and eclipse) of 64 bit including 64 bit NDK. Do you mean i need to use 32 bit NDK instead of 64?

Comment: well, i used ndk 9d 32 bit version and latest version of tess-two library. All is well now, app works perfectly, thank you for your response and update of that tess-two github library, :).